# Mongoose bcryptjs compare password doesn't refer to the document (this)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, mongoose-schema

I have mongoose schema like so

```
var mongoose  = require ('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;
var touristSchema = new Schema ({
    local: {
        email: String,
        password: String
    },
    facebook: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String,
    }
});


touristSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    console.log('bcrypt called by strategy', user);

// if user is facebook user skip the pasword thing.
if (user.facebook.token) {
    next();
}
// only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
if (!user.isModified('password') && !user.isNew){
console.log('I am in here', user.isNew);
return next();
}
// generate a salt
bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    console.log('I am in genSalt');

    if (err) return next(err);

    // hash the password using our new salt
    bcrypt.hash(user.local.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
        user.local.password = hash;
        next();
    });
  });
 });

touristSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.local.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        // console.log(this.local.password);

        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', touristSchema);
```

and login strategy like this

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
                User.findOne({ 'local.email': email }, function(err, user) {
                    if(err)
                        return done(err);
                    if(!user)
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No User Found'));
                user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
          if (err) throw err;
                    if (isMatch) {
                            done(null, user);
                    }
                    else
                         done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Incorrect password'));
      });
        });
    });
 }
));
```

everything is working as expected but when I try to log in it gives me error:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined**.
Turns out that *this.local* is undefined.
This is very strange as in `touristSchema.pre` hook we assigned `var user = this` and on logging this returned user document. When in compare method we are using `touristSchema.methods.compare` then `this` should must refer to the document as written in mongoose middleware docs too. I am beating my head over it for a couple of days now and have consumed every available help I could. Any help is greatly appreciated in advance. Thanks
and yes my
**mongnodb version** is v3.2.15
**mongoose version** is 4.9.7
which looks compatible to me according to mongoose docs